# Change global address list fields

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, outlook

In Outlook Global address lists, there are fields at the top. Name Title etc. I would like to change and remove some of these fields, but I cannot find how to do this. We are running Exchange 2010, Active directory on 2008 R2.

[image]

I would like to change the Location section.

Comment: What do you want to change exactly? The contents for each user or something else?

Comment: Hi, I would like to change where it say's Location on the the bar to another field, I.E Mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/4d87027d-3c5e-4329-a350-e711a2717912) an Outlook MVP states that it is not possible to customize the Outlook GAL dialog.  You can however code your own but it will only get called by your own code, maybe an add-in, etc.  Either way you cannot modify the default dialog window.